# In the React app, downloading an image from an iPhone to wi-fi is very slow, on the mobile Internet it’s excellent. Has anyone come across?

Tags: iphone, reactjs

There is an application written in React. Images are loaded using the following code:

```
<input type='file' id='single-file' onChange={props.onChange}/>


onChange = e => {
                let ua = navigator.userAgent;
                let is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;
                if (is_ie === true) {
                        let file = document.getElementById('single-file').files[0];
                        this.props.uploadImage(file);
                        this.props.openUpload(true);
                } else {
                        this.props.uploadImage(e.target.files[0]);
                        this.props.openUpload(true);
                        e.target.value = '';
                }
        };
```

sent as standard with axios module using FormData.

When testing, it was found that from the PC, and Android phones, sending files happens quickly and normally. But on the iPhone on the mobile Internet of the network, the photo is sent perfectly, but it takes about two to three minutes with wi-fi. Different iPhones (X, XR, 6, 7), different browsers, different wi-fi networks were tested - the result is the same.

Maybe someone faced a similar problem?

Comment: Is there any difference in broadband speed? A good online tool to test this with is [Speedtest.net](https://www.speedtest.net/)

Comment: mobile internet: download - 21.5, upload - 12.5
wi-fi: download - 18.2, upload - 9.53